# is there any way to correct this distortion? (THREE JS)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, babylonjs

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Desafio Three JS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/icy-currying-lgp1e?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=preview"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="icy-currying-lgp1e"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to learn a little bit of three.js... I have the following code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-currying-lgp1e

I should achieve something like that:

[image containing what I would like to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifui5.png)

An then:

[positions of this .stl object added to the scene should be read, to add new objects to it (buttons / cylinders) that are not sensitive to zoom, and when clicked they show a text from the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP1XZ.png)

I was trying to follow what is shown in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/0x1besz7/

But I couldn't go so far... I think it isn't loading correcly the STL file...

I've already tried: (i can't make this work)

```
xhr.open("GET", './assets/montagem-final.stl', true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.send(null);
```

// this should add my .stl object to the scene, and then place a cylinder over it...

```
let marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 16), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "yellow" }));
marker.geometry.translate(0, 0.25, 0);
marker.position.set(0, 5, 0);
scene.add(marker);

let scaleVector = new THREE.Vector3();
let scaleFactor = 10;

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
    let scale = scaleVector.subVectors(camera.position, marker.position).length() / scaleFactor;
    marker.scale.setScalar(scale);
    window.addEventListener("click", getClicked3DPoint);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

From that, there are distortions in the cylinders that I am placing. (I read them, and position them based on what was read, but they rotate and are not fixed where they should be).

Any kind of help will be very welcome, or indication of materials. Thank you in advance for your attention and helpfulness.

Comment: It would really be helpful if you'd put your working code in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: thanks! I tried that,but i had some problems loading some refs...
You can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-currying-lgp1e)